# 504 Error After Deploying AWS API with Terraform (Private Rest API)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

Hello I am receiving a 504 error after creating AWS private API deployed with terraform. Previously I was receiving a 502 error along with a AWS runtime error -->

```
Error: fork/exec /usr/local/bundle/bin/aws_lambda_ric: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

Any idea of possible remedies? Appreciate all the help!

1. Added correct query strings and header to invoke api url
2. Ran 2 versions of the image, one that included image configuration and another that did not
3. Deployed and tested images on two different binaries. ARM64 and AMD

One binary images gives the 504 error Error:

```
fork/exec /usr/local/bundle/bin/aws_lambda_ric: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint when reaching endpoint
```

the other provides timeout error 502 when I reach the endpoint